How to switch wayland to xorg on chromebook
I am using acer Chromebook 315 -4H and it has Linux with wayland enabled. Now I want to switch to xorg display from wayland, how can I do it?
Using chrome os I see many answers on internet but those are related to linux os (not chrome os)
I am using an application which works with xorg only.
